# UISplitViewController Render problem after using UIPopoverButton

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I started out with the UISplitViewController template in Xcode 4, and added a UIImageView that covers the whole detailViewController.

When i run the project the image and views render correctly. If i rotate the device it also renders correct, but if i hit the PopoverButton while in portrait and then rotate the device the image is rendered above the rootView..

[image: Bad rendering!!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to reproduce the bug you're experiencing, but without success. Could you provide information about how you add the image view and how you set its frame?

One possible solution that I can think of is setting:

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

in `viewDidLoad` of the detail view controller.

It would however be great if you could provide some code, so that I can reproduce the bug and tell you what's wrong.